# Meteor: How can I use the user account information for my app to login to a fork of the Telescope app?

Tags: meteor

I have an app where users have already signed up. When a user clicks the telescope button in my app, they will be transferred to another server in which I am running my own fork of the telescope app.

Upon going to telescope I want to be able to automatically log the user in with the same account information as in my app. How can this be done? I can adjust the code for both Meteor apps since I am running them myself.

Comment: If you don't have collections that are named the same in both apps, you could share a database by setting the mongo environment variable to be the same on both apps.

Comment: Ah yah, the only thing is I would have to ensure compatibility between our users collection.

Comment: Yes, maybe create different publications for the two different apps where you only publish specific fields for every app. That way, as long as you don't have fields named the same in both apps, no issues should arise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Telescope app to use the accounts database of your other application.

You can do this by altering the `Accounts.connection` to use another Meteor app (your main app)

Add this line into your telescope app somewhere in the `/server/lib` directory:

```
var myOtherAppDDP = DDP.connect("http://your-other-app.com");

Accounts.connection = myOtherAppDDP;
```

This way the DDP connection for your accounts section of your meteor app will use your main apps database.

Next you need to transfer the login-tokens to the other app. For this you need to make a special link with the users current login token:

```
Template.registerHelper("telescopeUrl", function() {
    return "https://your-telescope-app.com/?auto-login?token=" + localStorage.getItem("Meteor.loginToken") + "&userid=" + localStorage.getItem("Meteor.userId");
});
```

Then you can create a url:

```
<a href="{{telescopeUrl}}">Telescope App</a>
```

Lastly, you need telescope to intercept these links and log in, you can create a route for this with iron router.

Again, create a file in `/client/lib` that contains something like this:

somefile.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route("loggin_in", {
        onBeforeAction: function() {
            var token = this.params("token");
            var userId = this.params("userid");

            localStorage.setItem("Meteor.loginToken", token);
            localStorage.setItem("Meteor.userId", userId);

            Tracker.flush();

            window.location.href="/";

        }
    });
});
```

somefile.html

```
<template name="logging_in">
    <h3>Logging you in</h3>
</template>
```

I've never tried it personally, but hopefully it is helpful.